# How can I simplify (speed up) the selecting query from a database that contains more than 1 million records using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have two models in my application: Clients from where the client name is taken and Payments where the information about purchase is taken from. In the result I get the list of every client's purchases in the time intervals - `fromDate` and `toDate`. But all this process takes too much time. Because the client's db is around a 1.500 records and payments = 0.5 mln. So how can I speed up this process?

```
public async Task<List<SomeModel>> SomeMethod(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
{
    var clients = await _db.Clients.ToListAsync();

    var totals = new List<SomeModel>();

    foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        var payment = await _db.Payments.Where(pay => pay.ClientId == client.Id).Where(
            p =>
                DateTime.Compare(p.TradeDate, (DateTime)fromDate) >= 0 &&
                DateTime.Compare(p.TradeDate, (DateTime)toDate) <= 0).ToListAsync();
        var totalsByCust = new SomeModel{ Username = client.Username };
        foreach (var item in payment)
        {
            totalByCust.Bcf += item.Bcf;
            totalByCust.Ecn += item.Ecn;
            totalByCust.Ecbt += item.Ecbt;
            totalByCust.OpenGl += item.OpenGl;
            totalByCust.JeyK += item.JeyK;

        }
        totals.Add(totalByCust);
    }
    return totals;
}
```

Comment: @rene what's gonna happen? This process will take the same amount of time on the server...(

Comment: No, it won't, try it.

Comment: A SQL `JOIN` will be much more efficient than serially sending 1500 queries to the DB server.

Comment: @rene my bad, edited.

Comment: @it isn't. the last edit I believe :p

Comment: Do you have navigation properties on your `Client` DbSet that points at `Payments`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain only clientId, if I got u right

Comment: In your payment table in the database does `TradeDate` have an index or is used in an index?

Comment: @rene no it doesn't. it's just a simple column about a purchase date

Comment: run a profiler to see if it doesn't need one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have a navigation property on Payment to Client. Alternatively, you can load up all the clients into a dictionary since there is only 1500 of them.  This is how you would do it with a navigation property:

```
public async Task<List<SomeModel>> SomeMethod(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
{
  return _db.Payments
    .Where(p =>
        DateTime.Compare(p.TradeDate, (DateTime)fromDate) >= 0 &&
        DateTime.Compare(p.TradeDate, (DateTime)toDate) <= 0))
    .GroupBy(p=>p.ClientId)
    .Select(g=>new SomeModel { 
      UserName = g.First().Client.UserName,
      Bcf = g.Sum(p=>p.Bcf),
      Ecn = g.Sum(p=>p.Ecn),
      Ecbt = g.Sum(p=>p.Ecbt),
      OpenGl = g.Sum(p=>p.OpenGl),
      JeyK = g.Sum(p=>p.JeyK)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: The downside to this is that if you have a client with no Payments in that date range, they won't show up.

Comment: You should probably call this method SomeMethodAsync as well since it is a truly async method.

Comment: You're right, sir. I'll rename it...and yes, it is a truly async method that receives a lot of queries in a line

Answer (score 0):

Combining the queries is probably the most straightforward thing to try:

```
public async Task<List<SomeModel>> SomeMethod(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate) {
    var totals = new List<SomeModel>();

    var clientswithpayments = await _db.Clients.Select(client => new {
        client.Username,
        payments =  _db.Payments.Where(pay => pay.ClientId == client.Id).Where(p =>
            DateTime.Compare(p.TradeDate, (DateTime)fromDate) >= 0 &&
            DateTime.Compare(p.TradeDate, (DateTime)toDate) <= 0)
    }).ToListAsync();

    foreach (var client in clientswithpayments) {
        var totalsByCust = new SomeModel { Username = client.Username };
        foreach (var payment in client.payments) {
            totalByCust.Bcf += payment.Bcf;
            totalByCust.Ecn += payment.Ecn;
            totalByCust.Ecbt += payment.Ecbt;
            totalByCust.OpenGl += payment.OpenGl;
            totalByCust.JeyK += payment.JeyK;

        }
        totals.Add(totalByCust);
    }
    return totals;
}
```

Processing it all in the query is trickier, but probably the right answer:

```
public async Task<List<SomeModel>> SomeMethod2(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate) {
    var totals = _db.Clients.Select(client => new {
        client.Username,
        payments = _db.Payments.Where(pay => pay.ClientId == client.Id).Where(p =>
            DateTime.Compare(p.TradeDate, (DateTime)fromDate) >= 0 &&
            DateTime.Compare(p.TradeDate, (DateTime)toDate) <= 0)
    }).Select(cwp => new SomeModel {
        Username = cwp.Username,
        Bcf = cwp.payments.Sum(),
        Ecn = cwp.payments.Ecn.Sum(),
        Ecbt = cwp.payments.Ecbt.Sum(),
        OpenGl = cwp.payments.OpenGl.Sum(),
        JeyK = cwp.payments.JeyK.Sum()
    }

    return await totals.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: it faster, but takes alot of RAM

Comment: what about the single query solution?

Comment: I have tried this way and then I've got systemOutOfMemory exception :) This way takes more than 1 GB RAM. Anyway, thanks for ur attention. I really apperciate it!

Comment: With the single query solution? BTW, I had a typo in the single query solution SomeModel creation of the sum fields that I just fixed.

Comment: Yeap, it inadmissibly

Answer (score -1):

Move this code to a traditional SQL Statement using an SQLCommand. The Linq query is working line by line, and you get more efficiency when you use a batch query.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Store Procedure instead of Linq Query.